# Can EDI document contain a NUL (0x00) character inside?

Tags: edi, x12, edifact

I have a question about EDI document (either x12 or edifact format),
Does anyone know that can it contain a NUL (0x00) character inside?
Since I am implementing an EDI parser and parsing terminates once it encounters NUL char.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, of course it can.
in edifact, there are character sets, eg UNOA, UNOB, UNOC.
0x00 is not part of UNOA, but it is part of UNOC (AFAIK).
x12: I am not sure. They have rules, but AFAIK not well followed.
btw, for an open source edifact/x12 parser see: http://bots.sourceforge.net

Comment: what I try to say with: "yes of course it can" is: you can expect anything to come in. But it is not always valid.